# Preserving tab and line-break while insert JSON string into Document in MongoDB

Tags: json, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm inserting new document to `MongoDB` as following:

```json
db.crawl_api_config.insertOne({
    apiHost: "logbasex.github.io",
    apiUrl: "20221",
    contentType: "Blog",
    headers: "",
    jsonPath: {
        "items": {
            "path": "arts",
            "name": "item",
            "type": "ArrayObject"
        }
    },
    parameters: ""})
```

And after insert this document, I double-check the database to make sure the JSON field is well-defined, but there is something wrong:

```json
{"items": {"path": "arts", "name": "item", "type": "ArrayObject"}}
```

All tabs and line-breaks were disappeared. I don't know why. Is there any solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't inserted a *JSON string*. You inserted a *document* which is, basically, a *mapping* of keys to values. As such the only parts of the mapping are the keys and the values, not whitespace you used to format the document in your source code.

You could insert an actual *JSON string*, but it would be in fact a string and not a key-value mapping which would make it very awkward to work with:

```
db.crawl_api_config.insertOne({
    apiHost: "logbasex.github.io",
    apiUrl: "20221",
    contentType: "Blog",
    headers: "",
    jsonPath: "{\
        \"items\": {\
            \"path\": \"arts\",\
            \"name\": \"item\",\
            \"type\": \"ArrayObject\"\
        }\
    }",
    parameters: ""})
```

Comment: Did you try it yet?

Comment: Syntax Error Exception occurred. @D. SM